# Mark last day of season

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have an issue with my dataset, where I would like to mark a last day of the season(Discount, Not discount) and I am absolutely without ideas. The marking should be a new variable (values - last day, standard day)

```
data = {
    'start_day': [
        '2008-01-01',
        '2008-01-02',
        '2008-01-03',
        '2008-01-04', 
        '2008-01-05'
    ],
    'start_day_no': [
        1,
        2, 
        3,
        4, 
        5
    ],
    'Season': [
        'Discount',
        'Discount', 
        'No_discount', 
        'No_discount', 
        'Discount'
    ],        
}
frame = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

So if I look on my full dataset, I would like to mark the last day of discount season (blue) and last day of standard price (red), however with the condition that the season lasts at least for 20 days (so red start of 2016 doesn't count as a season).

[image]

Any hints, please? Thank you!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do it in steps like this:

Creating on year's mock data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'Season':['No_discount']*16+
                            ['Discount']*90+
                            ['No_discount']*202+
                            ['Discount']*25+
                            ['No_discount']*33}, 
                  index=pd.date_range('2016-01-01','2016-12-31', freq='D'))

df['grp'] = (df['Season'] != df['Season'].shift()).cumsum()

df['grp_size'] = df.groupby('grp').transform('count')

df.groupby('grp').tail(1).query('grp_size >= 20') #Filtering groups smaller than 20
```

Output:

```
                 Season  grp  grp_size
2016-04-15     Discount    2        90
2016-11-03  No_discount    3       202
2016-11-28     Discount    4        25
2016-12-31  No_discount    5        33
```

Where the index of the dataframe are the last dates of each group.

```
df_out = df.groupby('grp').tail(1).query('grp_size >= 20')
df_out.index.strftime('%Y-%m-%d').tolist()
```

Output:

```
['2016-04-15', '2016-11-03', '2016-11-28', '2016-12-31']
```

Comment: Cool! I tihnk that `df['grp'] = (df['Season'] != df['Season'].shift()).cumsum()` is main thing what was I thinking about. How to unite some bundle of same values! Thx

Comment: @LukášTůma Great!  Happy coding!  Yes, the `cumsum` trick is really useful.  Would you mind [accepting](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work?answertab=votes#tab-top) this solution?